# Start matching string from a certain point js

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you start js `.match` from a certain point in a string instead of starting from `0`?
for example, matching all string between `[]` 
String: `[abcd][efgh][iklm]`
string`.match(/\[\]/g)` would return `[abcd],[efgh],[iklm]`
but instead, I wanted it to return something like `[efgh],[iklm]`

Answer (score 0):

You could have used this regex to avoid matching 1st `[]`

```
(?<=\].*?)\[.*?\]
```

But,Javascripts regex engine **doesn't** support `lookbehind`! So,it won't work

---

Instead use this regex

```
\[.*?\]
```

and avoid the first match

Comment: I wanted to take value out of the string, not to add to an array

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the first (or another defined number) set of brackets you could do something like this:

```
var string = "[abcd][efgh][iklm]";
var new_string = string.match(/\[.*?\](\[.*\])/, $1)[1];
```

The $1 group skips over the stuff in the first set of brackets. If you want to skip more than one set of brackets, though, you'd have to add another `\[.*?\]` before the stuff in the parentheses, so this doesn't work if your text isn't uniform.

Edit -- you  could also slice off the first however many characters that you want to exclude first, but again, this depends on you knowing how many characters you want to slice off.

```
var string = "[abcd][efgh][iklm]";
var new_string = string.slice(6, string.length);
var final_string = new_string.match(/^\[.*\]$/)[0];
```